# Spark - How to deal with updates

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions

I'm facing a problem about updating the rows in a data lake. Let's says that we have records coming from somewhere. Those records needs to be written on HDFS/AzureBlobStorage/wherever.
Let' suppose that our records have a unique ID.
Let's say that we already have written some records without any duplicated ID.
So we have:

```
ID      |    name
1       |   Andrew
2       |   Bob
3       |   Alice
```

(It's an example so I used just a field to update) We have those records save on HDFS/AzureBlobStorage/wherever.
Now, a new record arrive:

```
ID=1  name=Mark
```

what we want to do is to update this record. Is it possible something like that?
A solution that comes in my mind is save all records with a timestamp and use an aggregation on a window ordered by the timestamp (descending) keeping the first row.

Do you have any solution that would make me have any time **only** the most updated row? I don't think it is possible, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Look for the scd type1 implementation. That will overwrite the existing records.

Answer (score 0):

Typically Apache Spark does not support direct updates on the RDD/dataframes and on the underling data source, however there are 3rd frameworks that allows this. One of them is [delta.](https://delta.io/)

If you want to achieve this from spark, then one approach is to store all the events that changes the data and reply the current state as processing all log of events.

Comment: I will give a try to Delta. I don't know it. Thank you!